# Janus-Gateway RTP-Forward to send stream to AWS Elemental MediaLive

Tags: amazon-web-services, webrtc, rtp, janus-gateway, aws-elemental

I'm using rtp_forward from the videoroom plugin in Janus-Gateway to stream WebRTC. 
My target pipeline looks like this:

WebRTC --> Janus-Gateway --> (RTP_Forward) MediaLive RTP_Push Input

I've achieved this:

WebRTC --> Janus-Gateway --> (RTP-Forward) Janus-Gateway [Streaming Plugin]

I've tried multiple rtp_forward requests, like:

`register = {"request": "rtp_forward", "publisher_id": 8097546391494614, "room": 1234, "video_port": 5000, "video_ptype": 100, "host": "medialive_rtp_input", "secret": "adminpwd"}`

But medialive just doesn't receive any stream. Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with AWS MediaLive: initially I thought that, since most media servers like this expect RTMP and not RTP, that was the cause of the issue, but it looks like it does indeed support a plain RTP input mode. At this point this is very likely a codec issue: probably MediaLive doesn't support the codecs your browser is sending (opus and vp8?). Looking at the supported codecs, this seems to be the issue: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/inputs-supported-containers-and-codecs.html

You can probably get video working if you use H.264 in the browser, but audio is always Opus and definitely not AAC, so you'll need an intermediate node to do transcoding.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using RTP PUSH, Are you pushing stream it to correct RTP endpoint provided by AWS ? If so, you can see alerts in health check if Medialive received it but it failed to read or corrupted. You'll see error is any of these pieplines where you're pushing the stream, if you don't see anything which means some Network problem, try RTMP as it's on TCP and should get something in packet capturer.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/monitoring-console.html